Need to header value in all the files while writing in PySpark for txt files
I need to write header value to all the files in txt format
Here is the code
data = [
    ("John", 25, "USA"),
    ("Alice", 30, "Canada"),
    ("Michael", 35, "USA"),
    ("Emily", 28, "Australia"),
    ("David", 40, "UK"),
    ("Sophia", 32, "Canada")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("sample_test")

df_columns = str(df.columns)[1:-1]
df_columns = df_columns.replace("'", "")

df_final = spark.sql(f"select 'name,age,country', 0 as dummy_col union all select concat_ws(',',{df_columns}), 1 as dummy_col from sample_test")

df_final = df_final.coalesce(1).orderBy("dummy_col").drop("dummy_col")
spark_options = {"maxRecordsPerFile": "3", "emptyValue": "", "header": "true"}
df_final.write.format("text").mode("append").options(**spark_options).save("path")

When i am using text format header is not coming in all the file, but when i using csv file format with below code it is working fine.
data = [
    ("John", 25, "USA"),
    ("Alice", 30, "Canada"),
    ("Michael", 35, "USA"),
    ("Emily", 28, "Australia"),
    ("David", 40, "UK"),
    ("Sophia", 32, "Canada")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Age", "Country"])

spark_options = {"maxRecordsPerFile": "3", "emptyValue": "", "header": "true"}
df.write.format("csv").mode("append").options(**spark_options).save("path")

Final output expected
file1.csv
Name,Age,Country
John,25,USA
Alice,30,Canada
Michael,35,USA

file2.csv
Name,Age,Country
Emily,28,Australia
David,40,UK
Sophia,32,Canada

Note: For text we have used concat_ws since text will consider only one column.
Please help me to get header in all the files while writing in text format using Pyspark.

Text format does not support the use of headers. You should consider using other formats.
